# does an index provide order by itself?

Tags: sql, indexing

lets say I have

```
create table mytable(
 a VARCHAR(200)
 b VARCHAR(200)
 c VARCHAR(200)
)

create index on mytable (b)
```

if I select

```
select a, b, c from mytable;
```

would it be sorted by b?

Comment: all 4 answers are usefull. thank you all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two main types of indexes: clustering and non-clustering.

The clustering index determines physical row order in a table. Inserting into a table (or updating the respective field) causes the database engine to re-order the data so the field with the clustering index on it is sorted correctly. That's why there can only be one clustering index on any table.

Non-clustering indexes are copies of the columns, ordered as desired. They exist separately, and physical row order is not connected to them. That's why there can be as many non-clustering indexes as you want.

Most often a simple select on a single table returns the rows in physical order, so it would not be surprising to receive them sorted the way the the clustering index is.

However, this is not guaranteed and you should not rely on it. *Always* include an ORDER BY  clause if the result set order is of any concern.

If you order by the clustering index, there is not much work to do for the DB engine, but your intent is clear.

If you order by a non-clustering index, there is a little more work to do for the DB, but (depending on table size and data type) it will be orders of magnitude faster than ordering by an entirely unindexed field.

Comment: the real problem I have is that I have a log table which should save in and out message, I want to do a normal select top 2 and trust the second row will be the out message. but as you say I should not rely on it and order by id ... at least.

Comment: @dnuske: If you have a strictly increasing field (like a date value in a log table) and a message type maybe, then create a clustering index over `(dateval, msgtype)`. Then ORDER BY these fields and take your TOP 2 and all should be well. And blazingly fast, too. If the date value is *not* strictly increasing, don't use a clustering index, but a normal one. Reordering the entire table physically when you insert rows "in the middle" kills insert performance, so it should be avoided.

Comment: Just out of interest, why pick this as the answer when I said the same thing, albeit in a more succint manner, 12 minutes previous?

Comment: @dnuske: If you also need to filter/order by message type at some point, a normal index over the message type field would be necessary. Indexes can only be used from "left to right", i.e. a composite index over `(dateval, msgtype)` can not be used to to do something with `msgtype` alone (but it could be used to do something with `dateval` alone).

Comment: @KierenJohnstone it's just because this answer is more useful to me. sometimes an answer comes with another question attached, explained answers prevent this. but I vote up your answer anyway

Answer (score 6):

Perhaps (more likely in the case of clustered indexes I would imagine), but you cannot rely on this or expect it.  Unless you have an `order by`, assume it will not be ordered.

Answer (score 5):

You should *never* assume that data returned by a query to a RDBMS will be in any particular order. The only way to be certain that the data is ordered is to explicitly request (generally with the `ORDER BY` clause) for the database engine to sort and order the data returned by the query.

Comment: And still, if you expect it to be sorted the same way your own program would sort it, you should care about the NLS layer (Oracle for example has `NLS_SORT = BINARY`).

Answer (score 4):

**No, because you aren't using the index on `b` in your sample query.**

That would use a clustered index scan or a table scan.

And, as Kieren rightly points out, there is no implicit order in SQL.  Even if you did use an index in your query, result order can be affected by things you have little to no control over, like internal joins (hash match, merge join, nested loops) that the query engine uses.

If you want an ordered result, use `ORDER BY`.